# How do I make correct data statement in Fortran?

Tags: fortran

```
  subroutine mindef(f)
  implicit real*8(a-h,o-z)
  real*8 r(6),com(3)    
 data r/"en d", "irec","tion","prog","ress","ion "/, &
   & nl , ng , np/"l" , "g" , "p"/, "itra1","itra2"/"*" , " "/
```

I got the following message:

```
fitold.f90:346:39:

        & nl , ng , np/"l" , "g" , "p"/, "itra1","itra2"/"*" , " "/
                                   1
Error: Syntax error in DATA statement at (1)
```

Comment: It's just too difficult to maintain the IBM360 style non-standard Fortran from over 40 years ago, particularly when you combine it with the free-form source format of later standards.  You would want to declare r and c explicitly as character strings; as a first step in testing, you might use arrays of character(len=8).

Answer (score 2):

A data statement takes pairs of object lists and value lists, where such a pair is of the form `object-list /value-list/`.  The objects (excluding cases of *data implied dos*) to be initialized must be variables.  In the case of the data statement of the question, this is violated around the point of the error message marker.

Let's look at the statement of the question:

```
  data r / "en d", "irec","tion","prog","ress","ion "  / , &
!      ^ ^ '----------------------------------------'  ^ ^
!      | |                    '- value list            | '- pair separator
!      | '- separator                                  '- separator       
!      '- variable name
     & nl , ng , np   /  "l" , "g" , "p"   / , "itra1","itra2"  /"*" , " "/
!      '-----------'  ^  '--------------'  ^ ^ '--------------'
!          '- object  |        '- value    | |       '- NOT VARIABLES!
!              list   |            list    | '- pair separator
!                     '- separator         '- separator
```

As we now see, we have character literals where the compiler expects to see object names.

---

As tim18 comments, even this correction won't make the code fragment standard Fortran.  Some compilers accept character values for initializing/assigning to real values (and `real*8`), but this isn't universal.